# Lightbox not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox, imagemap

I have a css image map using Lightbox that works in other browsers except IE8.

have tried:
changing the doctype,
no extra lines of javascript,
no extra commas,
images not in cmyk,

using pretty photo instead (not sure how to incorporate it into the image map),
reading other posts on this topic.

website:http://heidiwallaceart.com/currentwork.html

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have a strict doctype on your website, whilst the HTML output does not adhere to this strict doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Make sure to change that with a HTML5 doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

In addition several resources are not found, double check all the paths:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
http://heidiwallaceart.com/css/none
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://heidiwallaceart.com/img/close.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://heidiwallaceart.com/img/loading.gif
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://heidiwallaceart.com/img/next.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://heidiwallaceart.com/img/prev.png
```

Comment: Put the img on the server and changed the doctype, still no luck.

Comment: checked that the img folder is not in any other folder